# C preprocessor: removing quotes from an argument

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor, quotes

I'm abusing the **C** preprocessor for my build system to produce a "readme" plain-text file and a web page from the same source file. The construction is something like this:

The actual definitions are in `data.h`:

```
#define WEBSITE "http://example.com"
```

Note that the `//` in the URL must be quoted, or else it will be treated as the start of a comment. A similar problem occurs when using a `,` in the argument; the quotes are necessary, or else the comma would be treated as an argument separator.

Using this header, a file `readme.txt.pp` is run through the **C** preprocessor:

```
#include "data.h"
Visit the website at WEBSITE!
```

Of course, the preprocessor output is:

```
Visit the website at "http://example.com"!
```

The quotes appear in the output. Is there any way, or workaround, to get this code to give the output:

```
Visit the website at http://example.com!
```

I'm using Visual C++ 2008. I know that the preprocessor is not the ideal tool for this job; suggestions that use other built-in VC++ features are also welcome. (I tried XML with XSLT, but it is impossible to include one XML file into another, which was a show-stopper.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding XSLT, have a look at the [`document()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document) function to read from multiple source documents.

I don't think there's any way to remove the quotes from the value of `WEBSITE`, since they are there in the definition of the macro. You might consider using the [`m4`](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) macro processor instead of the C preprocessor.

Comment: `document()` is a lifesaver! Reverting back to XSLT now :)

Answer (score 2):

Probably being late for Thomas, this might, however, still be useful for anyone lately stumbling over this question like me...

Try this:

```
#define DUMMY  
#define WEBSITE http:/DUMMY/example.com
```

So the line comment disappears, and the preprocessor resolves DUMMY to nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the C++ style comments if possible. I don't know how that works in VS, but using a GCC compiler I can pass the  `-std=c89` flag to gcc to disable C++ style comments and hence making

```
#define WEBSITE http://example.com
```

possible.

Comment: Yes, but not `#define SOMETEXT Hello, world!`, because of the comma.